# What is club soda and how do I make it?

Tags: soda

After many searches on the Google, I still can't find out *how* to make club soda.  So, I have to ask the question - what is club soda exactly?

I bought a [iSi Soda Siphon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00007JXR7) and have figured out how to make carbonated water (finally).

Now what do I have to do to make club soda?  How about seltzer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Seltzer and carbonated water are the same thing. Club soda is slightly different. ["Seltzer" comes from German:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seltzer_water)

> The term seltzer water is a genericized trademark that derives from
>   the German town Selters, which is renowned for its mineral springs.
>   Naturally carbonated water has been commercially bottled and shipped
>   from this town since the 18th century or earlier. Generally, seltzer
>   water has no added sodium salts, while club soda still retains the
>   sodium salts.

So, the primary difference is that seltzer has no added ingredients, but [club soda does](http://www.ehow.com/facts_6126819_club-soda-vs_-seltzer-water.html#ixzz1tOKxew93):

> Sodium bicarbonate, sodium chloride, sodium phosphate and sodium
>   citrate are added to club soda…

[Here's a decent review](http://www.thekitchn.com/good-question-whats-the-differ-1-85739) of the ingredients list and taste of various types of fizzy water.

So to answer your question directly, you can make seltzer just by carbonating regular tap water, and you can make club soda by adding potassium bicarbonate, potassium sulfate, or baking soda to water and carbonating it.

Comment: Nice work.  That was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

2tsps of baking soda for 1 liter of tap water better if filtered. 
1 liter =1.05 quart
Add squirt of lemon to help make the medicine go down
Good luck

Comment: What about the carbonation?

Answer (score 1):

I carbonate both 33 oz and 20 oz bottles of water (the sizes of the bottles I bought club soda in at the Giant).  I add a 1/16th of a teaspoon of potassium citrate powder and 1/32nd of a teaspoon of potassium bicarbonate to both sizes...just a little lighter on the citrate for the 20 oz.  I carbonate the bottles for 45 seconds with a five pound CO2 cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that club soda and sparkling water are similar but not the same. You can make club soda by mixing baking soda and tap water together.

Comment: This answer could be better by adding proportions. Welcome to Seasoned Advice.