# How to make club soda

Tags: water, soda

What would be the proportions of potassium bicarbonate & potassium sulfate added to one litre of water before carbonating it?

Comment: duplicate of this ? http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/23446/what-is-club-soda-and-how-do-i-make-it